# Removing Quotation Marks from string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

Given a list :

```
q = ['"hello','it's','me']
```

I want to remove "'s" and the '"' at the beginning of hello to obtain:

```
q = ['hello','it','me']
```

I wrote:

```
for i in ['"s','"']:
    q = [w.replace(i,'') for w in q]
```

This results in `q=['"hello",'it','me']`. The code does not seem to work for the quotation marks.

Comment: It's a syntax error right now for q. (You have one unclosed single quotation)

Comment: You're replacing double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

(I cannot comment because I don't have enought points so please excuse me for posting as an answer).

First your initial list q is not valid, the *'it's* element will throw invalid syntax.

The easiest will be to sanitize your list elements before they're pushed, is this possible for you? For example, in the case of double quotes use

```
element = '"hello'
element.replace('"', '')
```

In the case of the single quote and the s:

```
element = "it's"
single_index = element.find("'")
new_element = element[0:single_index]
```

I hope this helps